# What's the best library for automated-tests for IE with Python?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I am using Python to do automated tests for IE. Currently I use PAMIE. It can click links and find words very well if a web page has no iframes. However, some of my tested pages include several iframes, and PAMIE seems can't handle it correctly. It can't find the text strings in the iframes.

Does anyone recommend some Python libraries instead of PAMIE? Or is there a way to access iframes in a web page with PAMIE？ It's better if there is an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) with it's [Python client binding](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). Selenium can let you record your own workflow or write your own script in one of its supported languages. The tests are conducted on an actual browser as opposed to a simulated one. There's no system can top it at the moment.